# Preposition for time

Tags: prepositions

I know how to say
1) 13h00 "I will go in 1h" = I will go at 14h00

But
I also want to be able to say:
2) 13h00 "I will go in the hour" = I will go between 13h00 and 14h00

What kind of preposition I have to use to say the sentence (2)
I want a very simple way to say it, like with a preposition instead of "in".

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

"Within" would work here: "I will go within the hour" ([example](http://www.mirror.co.uk/money/tesco-hit-back-amazon-speedy-10692847))