# Preposition used for measurements

Tags: prepositions

So I've been writing [English] scientific articles for quite a while, but for years I've wondered what [preposition](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/prepositions.htm) is needed in the following sentence structure (just an example in my field of research, but it applies science-wide). I'm a non-native English speaker.

> We measured speech understanding scores *[preposition]* cochlear implant
>   users.

[preposition] options as far as I can see:

- ***in*** : is technically awkward, as speech understanding is tested by verbal testing and hence it's not an objective measure obtained *within* the body. However, it is commonly used in the scientific literature;
- ***of*** : sounds a bit weird, but technically it seems OK;
- ***from*** : also quite awkward, as it seems to imply something is taken from the study subjects;
- ***by*** : In a way this is a good choice, but requires a different sentence structure, like: *'We measured SRTs obtained by performing speech recognition....'*. This is OK, but more words are needed and the 'active' format of the sentence is lost. I therefore do not support this option.

Comment: Seems like "in" would be fine, if that's the standard prep used in the lit.

Comment: Seems like "of" would be fine.  The 'users' possess their 'scores'.

Comment: @MetaEd - why is this pob? If the answer below is correct, it's actually often used incorrect in the literature. If there's no hard rule that governs my question, that doesn't mean it's pob?

Comment: As it stands, the question is too broad -- it's a request for writing advice rather than a question about a specific element of English or English usage.

Comment: @MetaEd - Thanks for helping me here. Interesting motivation. Should I go to [writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) instead? Can you migrate if yes?

Comment: @MetaEd - further, I see [questions like this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/396023/preposition-for-time?rq=1) being asked in the past. How is that different from mine?

Comment: I don't think that *in* sounds wrong. But *among* is also a good choice. (Although I agree with the answer that the sentence should be rephrased in general.)

Comment: @AliceD Stack Exchange sites are curated by volunteers who work as time permits. The posting rules apply to every post, but the attention actually paid to individual posts varies from day to day, and the way that volunteers understand and handle each situation varies also. This means the rules will necessarily be enforced inconsistently.

Comment: @AliceD That linked question should have been closed immediately for lack of research effort.

Comment: @AliceD [writing.se] is not a bad choice, but for scientific articles another good choice is [academia.se]. You might even want to look at whatever stack supports your specific discipline.

Comment: @MetaEd - *AliceD Stack Exchange sites are curated by volunteers who work as time permits* - yep, I know the drill (I'm modding  2 sites). Just wondering where to go with these questions, because I run into such issues every now and then.

Comment: @MetaEd *whatever stack supports your specific discipline* - I'm a mod over at Bio and Psych&Neurosci - we close questions as posted above, because it's about English language and usage. So I can't go to the scientific stacks - I'd have to close my own question ;-).

Comment: @AliceD Just looking at the question, I think Writing over Academia. This is just because it doesn't seem to be a question that is specific to academia (wouldn't, for example, be treated in MLA or CMOS). Seems more like a question of the clearest way to express yourself. In fact, you might even get good help at [ELL.se]. Preposition choice is one of the very hard things for non-native users of English. It's hard even for native English speakers to clearly articulate why they use what they do. ELL experts often have a better handle on that particular problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically  speaking, you don't measure a speech understanding  score, you measure speech understanding and give it a score. The score isn't actually a property of the cochlear implant users, it's a property of your assessment of their speech understanding. You could say "We scored cochlear implant users on speech understanding" or "We measured the speech understanding of cochlear implant users and assigned them a score" or "We assigned cochlear implant users a score based on our measurement of their speech understanding".